# How can I notice when any viewcontroller is presented by presentModalViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For solving this issue, I tried to use KVO(key value observing) to monitor property named to 'presentedViewController'. I made a custom viewcontroller as a base viewcontroller which is used for the base viewcontroller of all of viewcontrollers in my application. Then, I add the following code to **initWithNibName:bundle:** of the viewcontroller.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"presentedViewController" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and, overriding observing method like that:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"object %@", object);
}
```

Finally, I made one viewcontroller derived from base viewcontroller that contains above codes.
When I used **presentModalViewController** method to make it modal viewcontroller. but, observing I installed didn't work. I expected that observing is hitted when the method is called. Unfortunately, nothing is happened.

In short, I have two question. First is why that is not work. the other is that there are any nice ways to achieve this goal.

**EDIT:**
I was able to get success by @jailani habeeb's way. Thank you @jailani habeeb.
In addition, I really wonder why KVO doesn't work. Any other property like 'title' is work well..

Comment: Try add observer in viewDIdLoad method.

Comment: @Greg It's not work. I had tried that.

Answer (score 1):

presentModalViewController was deprecated in iOS 6.  You can use presentViewController:animated:completion: instead.  You can do your logic in the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can subclass the UIViewcontroller and override the method

   presentViewController:animated:completion:
2. Then postnotification when any of the view controller is presented
3. Register for your view controller that notification wherever you
   need that notification

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It actually helps me to achieve my goal. What I really want to do is doing something before any viewcontroller is presented. So, your first way is good to this situation.